# How is unjustifiable (falsely attributed) usage of *we* or *us* called?

Tags: pronouns, rhetoric, category

I wonder what the name of phenomenon when a speaker uses *we* or *us* to falsely (and, really, deceptively) attach oneself to a group (like when a politician says "hard times await us" in his public speech, when hard times obviously don't await *him*) or place false collective blame (like in "we went to Iraq", when neither him, nor most of his listeners have even been there) is.

I've learned about something called *[nosism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosism)* and also I've read through ["Atypical uses of *we*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We#Atypical_uses_of_we) section here, but seems that none of the listed instances of usage of *we* fits my description. 
If these are actually instances of nosism I would like to know the precise name of its category.

UPD: Doesn't have to be a matter of linguistics: I simply need to name this rhetorical device.

UPD2: I continued the search was lead to words like *populism* and *demagoguery*, but they seem either unfit or too broad for the purpose of understanding.

UPD3: In case of the political speech, would "political *we*" be a better name? Still waiting for more general (but not too broad) name.

Comment: It is normal to use "we" in a situation where the speaker considers himself to be a member of the group being discussed.  Eg, if you were a fan of (choke!) the Green Bay Packers, it would be perfectly normal to shout "We won!" if indeed that team managed to end a game on top.  This is different from the "royal we", et al, of nosism.  (As to "unjustifiable", yes the technique is sometimes used by politicians to make them seem like "everyone else", but there really is no other standard way in English to denote the concept.)

Comment: @HotLicks: okay, but I'd like to know the precise name of the phenomenon.

Comment: Not clear that there is a name, linguistically, since it falls under the standard definition of "we".  There may be a term in philosophy or rhetoric that applies, though.

Comment: @HotLicks: well, perhaps I'm asking in the wrong sub. Could you point me to a more appropriate one?

Comment: No idea there, but you might look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We#Inclusive_and_exclusive_we) in the link you gave above to appreciate the ways in which English *does not* distinguish between various forms of "we".  From there you can wander off into *clusivity*, if your brain doesn't explode first.

Comment: I wonder what the name of x is. Not; I wonder what's the name of. Nosism is more commonly known as the "royal we". The politicians use the royal we and, therefore, indirectly, are acting as if they represent some group, which they sometimes do. It's a rhetorical trick: sophistry

Comment: @Lambie - Saying "we won" (or "we went to war") is not "the royal we".  The royal we is when the Queen says "We are displeased with you. Off with your head!"  In the royal we, "we" refers to only one person.

Comment: @Lambie: thanks for correction. *Sophistry: a method of argument that is seemingly plausible though actually invalid and misleading*. Quite unsure that it fits the description, and even if it does, it's way too broad.

Comment: No, Hot Licks, you are mistaken. That is the historical definition of it. But not the way it is used by others. Go do some research if you don't believe me. It's used by academics and politicians and others when they can get away with it.

Comment: @Lambie: "*Nosism is more commonly known as the 'royal we'.*" According to [Wikipedia (royal we)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we), at least: "*The* ***more general*** *word for the use of we to refer to oneself is nosism.*" Not that they are the same, but that *nosism* is more general than "royal we". Similarly, the [Wikipedia (nosism)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosism) page distinguishes various cases, of which the "royal we" is only one, one that "*refers to a single person holding a high office, such as a monarch, bishop, or pope.*" Do you disagree with these characterizations?

Comment: @Lambie: But I do see that one of the references on the Wikipedia nosism page says that "royal we" is essentially a synonym. Still, as you commanded Hot Licks, perhaps you could "go do some research" and point us to it?

Comment: @Lambie - Show us some documentation for your claims.

Comment: @The_Keeper - The fact is that using "we" in the situation you describe is not, in and of itself, demagoguery.  The English language does not provide a reasonable way to split hairs the way you would wish, and any attempt to make the distinctions you desire would simply increase the appearance of manipulation.

Comment: @HotLicks: well, I need to name the phenomenon :) what (unconventional) term would you suggest?

Comment: If I were going to name the usage of "we" being discussed, I would, for a non-technical term, call it the "collegial we".  It expresses the sense that the speaker is a "colleague" of others in the group of which he is speaking.  Whether this deserves to be then grouped with other usages under "nosism" is for others to judge.  (But it's not grouped there now.)

Comment: @HotLicks: nice suggestion)) could you think of a non-technical term specifically for "we the rulers" (disguised as "we the nation") usage?

Comment: Drew, I expect all you high-level English speakers to know this and agree with it. I mean.....but here you go: http://andrewnorton.info/2007/10/27/the-academic-we/

Comment: Here's another take, rather amusing: http://www.nytimes.com/2010/10/03/magazine/03FOB-onlanguage-t.html?_r=0

Comment: The "military we" might be an alternate term for the "collegial we".  Both would mean the same, though.

Comment: @Lambie - The "academic we" you refer to is just a variant of the "editorial we" and/or the "writer's we".

Comment: Yes, and it's all the same thing generically referred to as the royal we. Though it can be further broken down or be more specific. Maybe you would prefer "royal we".

Comment: Maybe you would prefer "the Churchill we":  *We shall fight in France, we shall fight on the seas and oceans, we shall fight with growing confidence and growing strength in the air, we shall defend our island, whatever the cost may be. We shall fight on the beaches, we shall fight on the landing grounds, we shall fight in the fields and in the streets, we shall fight in the hills; we shall never surrender.*

Comment: @Lambie - The *royal we* and the *editorial we* are entirely different.  The *royal we* applies only to (supposed) royalty, and everyone understands that it refers to a single person.  It is a holdover from the archaic *thee/thou* language of the past.  The *editorial (and writer's) we* pretends that the entire editorial staff (or group of writers) is in agreement, even though, in fact, there may only be one editor/writer or the head editor/writer may be enjoying dictatorial powers.  But its main purpose is to avoid the awkward "I" in editorials and academic papers.

Comment: In editorial environments, it's jargon to say the royal we.

Comment: After agc's answer, it's not POB anymore.

Comment: @Lambie Mistaken the same way as WS2. The OP's is referring to "false attribution."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Towards a term or phrase specifying the insincere usage of the **[inclusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clusivity) we** to promote a feigned consensus, and by the nose thus lead groups astray...

Pseudo-Formal:  The inclusive first person plural *in absentia*.

Informal:  The rogue's we.  The Machiavellian we.  We-selling.  We-hawkin'.  We minus one.

Comment: +1 *We-selling,* it is! Also a great marketing technique.

Answer (score -1):

The OED lists it as sense 2 of ***nosism***. See below, with a recent example.

> 2. With reference to an individual: the use of the word ‘we’ in stating his or her own opinions. rare.
>
> 2010   B. Zimmer in N.Y. Times Mag. 3 Oct. 18/2   Given the
>   accumulated resentment of ‘nosism’ (using we for I, from the Latin
>   pronoun nos), it’s little wonder that modern literary writers have
>   rarely tried to write narratives in the first-person plural.

The first sense of ***nosism*** is more general:

> 1. With reference to a group of people: a self-centred attitude, corresponding to egotism in an individual. rare before 20th cent.
>
> 1975   E. O. Wilson Sociobiol. 562   Nosism, hierarchical dominance
>   systems.., and trance-induction are among the elements of religious
>   behavior [which function] to circumscribe a social group.

Comment: Those just appear to be restatements of the royal we and the editorial we.

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks, my case is like "I and all the people [when there's in fact no consensus, or even in-group]", not like "we" in a scientific paper or as royal name.

Comment: The OP is about the _opposite_ of *nosism* -- here we want a name for the hypocritical use of an inclusive "we" in stating a group's opinion that is (secretly) not the public speaker's opinion.

Comment: @agc -- Actually, the OP is entirely unclear as to what he means, other than he apparently wants a derogatory term to use when discussing the speech of someone he disagrees with.

Comment: @HotLicks, the OP seems specific enough:  a rhetorical trope to describe the method of a speaker who employs the _inclusive we_ deceptively.  I didn't notice that Keeper expressed disagreement with any party, or even with the aforementioned Machiavellian  practice -- but even if he had, any such expression would be irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @agc - But "deceptive" is a judgment on the part of the observer and has nothing to do with classifying rhetorical usages.  Besides which there is already the English word "lying" which accurately describes deception.

Comment: Deception by speakers exists independently of observers.   'Lying ... describes ... deception' is tautological.  The OP wants a more specific term, as there are so many kinds of lies.

Comment: @HotLicks: as agc rightly put it, my concern is the **name** of the practice of using "we" when in fact "there's no us" (to the point when "we" becomes exclusive of the speaker and/or of most of the listeners)

Comment: @The_Keeper -- I gave you a proper name -- it's a "Churchill we".  Churchill was certainly not going to go fighting in France himself, nor were most of his listeners.  And, since that speech is so well known, "Churchill we" is a very easy term to explain and exemplify.

Comment: But Churchill was _sincere_:  he _was_ speaking inclusively for his nation.  Whereas the thing desired is a term for the action of some public persona that masks insincerity and secret plans, worn by one lying on behalf of a _part_ (if even _that_) of his or her nation or audience; e.g. like Churchill's most infamous opponent.

Comment: @agc - Sincerity is not a factor in rhetorical analysis.  The analysis of rhetorical devices is, in large part, an attempt to bypass subjective measures of sincerity and "truthfulness" and instead perform an objective analysis of a statement.  To demand that there be separate terms for "the insincere we" and "the sincere we" is subverting the analysis.

Comment: _Subjective_ measures?  We began with_a priori_ premises defining a phenomenon for which a satisfactory unknown term was sought.  As such there's not much to analyze ("to cut up"), rather, the task was one of assembling various parts.

Comment: @agc - The OP Is asking for the name of a rhetorical device.  A rhetorical device is independent of the sincerity of the individual using it.  Analysis of the use of such devices is therefore independent (or should be) of subjective measures.

Comment: [Quintilian's Oratory, Book IX, II, 44 - see "Irony".](https://archive.org/stream/institutioorator03quinuoft#page/399/mode/1up)  _Irony_ requires insincerity, and an audience that appreciates it.  QED.